# How can I do that if childclass do not call the fatherclass's override funtion, there will throw Error with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, extends

** Question: How can I do that if child do not call the father's override funtion, there will throw Error with TypeScript?**

```
class aaa {
  create() { }
}

class bb extends aaa {
  create() {
    // if not call the father's funtion, there will throw Error.
    // super.create()
  }
}
```

Comment: Just like  @Callsuper  in Android

Answer (score 0):

There is [an open issue for this on the TypeScript repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388) so it seems you can't do what you want directly.

There is interesting discussion in that issue, including workarounds like this:

```js
type callSuper = never;

class aaa {
  create(): callSuper { 
      return undefined as callSuper;
  }
}

class bb extends aaa {
  create() {
    // if not calling and returning the father's funtion, will throw Error.
    // return super.create()
  }
}
```

It is also mentioned that [for Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html), trying from a parent class to force or expect a child class to call systematically a function is an anti-pattern.

He suggests to use a [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) like this:

```js
class aaa {
    calledInTheParent(){
        this.create();
        // what needs to be always done here
    }

    protected create(){
        // this is just an empty hook to be overridden by children,
        // to let them do additional things 
    }
}

class bb extends aaa {
    protected create(){
        // do what you need in the child here without worrying 
        // about calling a parent function
    }
}
```